# Code sample in a list has no padding

Tags: bug, design, inline-code

This request is about how to make Stack Overflow better in 8 bytes: add padding to a code inside a list element.

This is `a code sample` in a paragraph. It looks nice.

- This is `a code sample` in a list. It has no padding.

This has come to my mind later:

### `A code sample` in a heading

Also has no padding.

Comment: `padding: 1px 5px;` is 17 bytes, not counting line-break, indentation and additional assignments.

Comment: `p code{padding:1px 5px 1px 5px;}` → `p code,li code{padding:1px 5px 1px 5px;}` in minified version. Relax dude, I've counted it up.

Comment: Ps. `code { padding: 1px 5 px } pre code { padding: 0 }` would be a better solution.