# Non existent question suggested as duplicate

Tags: support, similar-questions

On English Stack Exchange, when I try asking a new question with the title:**"Be available" V "Be available everywhere"**, the search box then proceeds to show me a list of possible similar questions, among which, I find the link: [Available or is available](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494094/available-or-is-available)

Clicking on it opens a new tab and redirects to a completely different and unrelated question: [Headline Language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104968/headline-language)

Why does that happen?

Comment: Yup. The question exists but is a duplicate. That said, we probably shouldn't be suggesting duplicates that are, themselves, duplicates of something else.

Comment: I've [posted a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366378/add-a-toast-notification-when-an-anonymous-user-follows-a-link-to-an-unanswered) asking for an alert to be implemented when a logged-out user is redirected from an unanswered duplicate to its target, to make situations like yours clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question you're redirected to is available for you here: [Available or is available](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494094/available-or-is-available?noredirect=1) . Because it's closed as a duplicate, and you were not logged in while asking your question, you were redirected to the 'original', the 'target' of the duplicate closure. This is automatically done for anonymous (non-logged-in) users, because it doesn't cause them to manually click the duplicate link.

However, the duplicate suggestions by the search box aren't really reliable. You shouldn't trust them in this case, they're **suggestions**, so *possible* duplicates; use your common sense. If it's not a duplicate, and [searching](https://english.stackexchange.com/search) didn't help, it's usually safe to post your question.