# Problematic sharing of a closed question that is linked to another answer on mobile

Tags: support, linked-questions, bug-reports

I was trying to share a link to the question *[How can I plot this Cartesian Equation in Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270409/how-can-i-plot-this-cartesian-equation-in-geometry-nodes)* that was closed and marked as duplicate.

I believe the question is not a duplicate, so I wanted to share it with a friend through [Facebook Messenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Messenger). It works fine and directs you to that exact question when you click the link from a desktop computer.

But when you click the link from a mobile device, it directs you to the linked answer. It looks like it functions as designed granting that the question is truly and unmistakably a duplicate question. If it truly was a product of design then it is inconsistent because the redirect post function on mobile and desktop computer do not behave the same way.

So based on this **inconsistency** I believe that this might actually be a bug. I want to share exactly the aforementioned link to a friend who is on mobile and not the linked answer. Is there a workaround to this? Or should I report this as a bug and where?

It might be helpful to add a checkbox in the popup that appears when clicking the Share link button. This "redirect" checkbox will be ticked by default so a user (who doesn't know about `?noredirect=1`) can untick it if they wish to share the exact thread and then they click copy link. Is there a chance this can be implemented?

[image]

---

And another issue is that sometimes I get a notice that I've been redirected and sometimes I don't (both cases as not logged in). In times it did give me notice, it was not helpful in my case because it does not give me an option to go to the link before it got redirected.

Here a screenshot of no notice that I got redirected even though I should have been notified since I was not logged in:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically redirect anonymous user from unanswered duplicate question to corresponding answered version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125220/automatically-redirect-anonymous-user-from-unanswered-duplicate-question-to-corr) - see also "As with migration and merge redirects you can disable with `?noredirect=1`"

Comment: hey thank you for this. quite manual but it will do for a techie myself. This is definitely problematic for a registered user who is not aware of this option. It probably should have been added in the share function with a checkbox that is ticked by default to redirect, and which we can untick then copy link. Is this possible to request?

Comment: actually it is not 100% duplicate question because there is still the inconsistency in behavior i have described between mobile and desktop computer. but i will say close it as duplicate for now.

Comment: You're not logged in on the mobile device, but are logged in on the computer. As the duplicate here says, users who aren't logged in who follow links to questions with no answers closed as duplicates will be redirected to the question which it's closed as a duplicate of unless `?noredirect=1` is present in the URL.

Comment: I have made a feature request to [show a notification when a user is redirected from an unanswered duplicate to its target](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366378/add-a-toast-notification-when-an-anonymous-user-follows-a-link-to-an-unanswered), which is useful as it often causes confusion in many cases, such as when one follows a link from search results.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thank you very much for the clarification! :) but unfortunately they did not implement your suggestion? because i can't see anythin telling me i got redirected. **EDIT** ahh i see the redirect at the top but it's not so useful because clicking the back arrow (on mobile) only returns me to messenger but not the original link before the redirect.