# MSE missing duplicate targets, other missing PostLinks

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I noticed a question here with a missing duplicate target and did a little digging.

According to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/445917) (or this [similar query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/446010) on `PostsWithDeleted`), on MSE, there are:

- 356 questions whose duplicate targets have been deleted.
- 5419 links whose duplicate *sources* have been deleted (users wouldn't notice this, e.g. [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) is the target of 78 missing questions).
- 503 entries in `PostLinks` where both the source and the target have been deleted (nobody would notice this either).

The first category should probably be cleaned up. The latter two categories above don't really matter since nobody will notice (and for posterity you might not want to break those links anyways), but the missing dupe targets are noticeable.

Exactly *how* they should be cleaned up is up in the air (reopening questions, deleting sources, reorganizing duplicates, copying posts over from MSO, etc.). I think this is more of an employee job, although as users I suppose we could do some reopening, if it's even worth the effort.

Comment: No, it's not related to the split. In the past users and moderators could delete a question even when there were other questions closed as duplicate of it. These days (not sure for how long) I'm pretty sure there is at least a warning. Edit: [little more than a year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239597/152859).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Do deleted questions appear in SEDE? I can't remember how that works.

Comment: @JasonC yes, deleted questions are a bit in `Postswithdeleted` but only with a fields actual set.

Comment: @rene Thanks. I didn't know `PostsWithDeleted` even existed. I'll rework these queries and update this post.

Comment: All right, I believe I've fixed my incorrect interpretation and updated this correctly.