# The source of a duplicated question is already removed, what to do with the duplicated question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Refer to this question here [Vehicle Dynamics Problem: Cornering wheels must slide on the road](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/443281/605), which has been closed because it is a duplicate of [Does the angular momentum of the cornering/turning car change the travel direction of the wheels of the car?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/435585/605)

But now the second question is removed and no longer existing. So the first question is now a duplicate of a non-existing question.

Should we do something about this situation? How to handle questions that are now the duplication of a removed questions?

Comment: How did that happen? Per [Auto-flag duplicates of deleted questions for reopening / deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221619/398063), posts that are dupe-targets shouldn't be eligible for deletion. And the question you linked happened way after that went live. Or am I reading that wrong? Can someone with enough Physics rep say if the dupe-target got Roombaed?

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain though the last activity on this question was _before_ it got changed to prevent such a situation :/ (not taking community deletion into account)